# Static library for Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, static-libraries, pcsc

I wrote a C++ static lib for Mac OS. It is for application run with smart card. Therefore, it used PCSC.framework. During compiling mylib, there is no problem and a static lib is derived. I created an application which was command line tool. I added my static lib to the application. When i created an instance from one class of the lib and called a method of the instance, i took errors undefined symbols for arcitecture x86_64: SCardConnect, SCardEstablishContext and the other pcsc functions

To solve these errors, i tried followings;

I rebuilt the static lib after changing architectures 32-bit intel from 64 bit. Then i also rebuilt  test application. But errors were continued similary. Just difference from the earlier, undefined symbols for arcitecture i386.

I have PCSC for both arcitectures x86_64 and i386. libccid was for i386. i run pcsctest correctly.

Please let me know how i can solve it.

Comment: Check one of the object files within your static lib by running `file object.o` on it. Does it show both, i386 and x86_64 code? Now do the same on your application binary or one of its object files.

Comment: Please don’t post the answer inside the question – people won’t find it easily. Post it as an answer instead.

Comment: the system didn't allow me to write an answer to my own question. so i edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Building the static library doesn't link and resolve all the symbols of the framework.  Take a look at the following similar questions:

- [Static Library using frameworks in specific projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009175/static-library-using-frameworks-in-specific-projects).
- [Include framework in Xcode static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908521/include-framework-in-xcode-static-library)

Some alternatives to consider are:

- Including PCSC.framework as a framework dependency of your
  application as you did with your library.
- Creating a framework or
  dynamic library instead of a static library.
- Calling dlopen/dlsym on PCSC.framework.